# Setting default parameters for a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, parameters

I am trying to set the default value of `@Day` to the current day. However, I am getting a couple errors on the initial `DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)` and on all the `@Day`s below it. I thought that the `@Day DateTime` under the alter procedure declared `@Day` but I am getting the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Day"

Anyone know what to do?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertWeeklyRuns]
    @Day DateTime = DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
AS  
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @Enddate DATETIME
    DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
    DECLARE @F1Runs INT
    DECLARE @F2Runs INT
    DECLARE @F3Runs INT
    DECLARE @F1Alarms INT
    DECLARE @F2Alarms INT
    DECLARE @F3Alarms INT

    SET @Day = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Day), 0) 

    SET @Enddate = CASE 
                      WHEN @Day > DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
                         THEN DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
                         ELSE DATEADD(Day, 1, @Day)
                   END

    SET @StartDate = @Enddate - 7
```

Thanks

Comment: Something seems a little off here. You are setting your variable and then checking the value of it with a case expression. Since you just set it there is no point in using the case expression, it will always return the first value.

Comment: You can't assign a nondeterministic default (e.g. `getdate()`, or any variant thereof). instead, set the default to `null`. Then within the body of your proc, if `@day` is null, set it to the default value you want. `select @Day = isnull(@day, cast(getdate() as date))`

Comment: @SeanLange All `Set @Day = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Day), 0)` does is take away time from whatever `@Day` is set to be. For example if someone set `@Day = 5/20/16 4:57` then `@Day = Set @Day = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Day), 0)` would take away the 4:57. The case statement comes into play if `@Day` is set to be a day in the future.

Comment: Ummm....no it won't. Look again. You set @Day to a value from DATEADD. Then in your next line you have a case expression which checks to see if the value of Day >= to the exact same calculation. Guess what...it will always be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work as you expected:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertWeeklyRuns]
    @Day DateTime
AS  
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

Declare @Enddate Datetime
Declare @StartDate Datetime
Declare @F1Runs Int
Declare @F2Runs Int
Declare @F3Runs Int
Declare @F1Alarms Int 
Declare @F2Alarms Int
Declare @F3Alarms Int
DECLARE @today date = CAST(GETDATE() AS date);

IF @Day IS NULL
    Set @Day = @today

Set @Enddate = CASE WHEN @Day >= @today THEN @today ELSE DATEADD(Day, 1, @Day) END

Set @StartDate = @Enddate - 7
END
```